# Calculating Eigenvectors of a Diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm feeling dumb even asking this. But there might be a definition for this somewhat like why $1$ is not a prime number. Therefor this might be the right place to ask this question anyway.

Given the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 \\
0 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

One sees immediately that the eigenvalues are $4$ and $4$ and the corresponding eigenvectors $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Assuming one doesn't see that or one tries to program this he would use
$(A-\lambda_i E)v_i=0$ to calculate the eigenvectors. 
But using this in this really simple example leads to 
$$\begin{gather}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}v=0
\end{gather}$$
So every solution would be correct for $v$.

Where is my mistake? I hope it is something obvious. I really hate it when there are special cases and one can not always use one scheme for all related problems.

Comment: In your particular example, every vector is an eigenvector with EV 4 - you're not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Every solution is valid for $v$ but we can easily see that each value within the eigenvectors are independent so we typically use the eigenvectors $[0,1]^T$, $[1,0]^T$ to represent this.

Comment: @PeterForeman that was one of those things which made me suspicious. I could choose two time the same eigenvector since every solution is correct, right? For example v1 and v2 = [1,1]. Wouldn't this mean they are not independent? I assumed the eigenvectors should in this case always be orthogonal to each other to show this independency.

Comment: Yes, if you choose the same one twice, or a multiple of an eigenvector, then they’re not linearly independent. So? That doesn’t prevent you from finding some other pair of eigenvectors that is linearly independent.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then there is no distinguished eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$. What you have is the corresponding eigenspace which is the kernel of $A-\lambda I$. This eigenspace is the often  represented by a basis, but the choice of the basis is not unique.

Comment: @amd ou okay. So basically I am doing this until I have two independent solutions. $[1, 1]^T$ and  $[2, 2]^T$ are both valid solutions, but I am not done yet ... Think I got it know. I came across this problem in minimal state-space-realization in control systems. Doing the SVD by hand I got not the same eigenvectors as the solution. I still have the mental model in my head that mine should look the same as in the solution. After all it will result in a controller which can not be arbitrary. I guess there has to be something else which makes the controller unique.

Comment: @trii I don't get the first part. $\lambda$ will always be an eigenvalue since it is the symbol for eigenvalues... However, the second part helped me a lot. The solutions I have mentioned in my comment to amd made use of the basis. I thought not much about it since every solutions is valid. Is this an usual approach to take two vectors of the basis as eigenvectors if they can not be clearly defined by two vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your calculations. Note that if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors corresponding to an eigenvalue  $\lambda $, so is $c_1v_1+c_2v_2$. In your case, note that  $e_1$ and $e_2$ are basis elements for $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This happens for any $n \times n$ identity matrix since the eigenvectors are always orthogonal and hence they span the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$ space. Thus, any vector in the space is an eigenvector. Therefore, there is no mistake in your solution.

Comment: The question here is: *Where is Mr. Sh4nnon's mistake?*

Comment: There isn’t one. But the matrix isn’t an identity matrix. I do like that one of the comments mentions eigenspaces, I think that would be a really nice term to see in an answer,